# Get value from regular expression

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have this regular expression:

```
company/(.*)-f(\d+).html$ company/view/$2
```

In view method of company class I use `$this->uri->segment(3)` to get the value of `$2`; I can't understand why  can't get the value of $2 just like variable.

```
public function view($param)
{
 echo $param; // no value returned
 $this->uri->segment(3) // works fine
}
```

Comment: can't see what this has to do with regex? the method you outlined works fine (controller/view/foo -> controller/view($param) will output foo. are you trying to set up routing?

Comment: Could you describe your problem clearly? Please provide a detail background why you choose Regex as a solution to your problem, maybe we can propose something better.

Comment: Presumably there is a rewrite rule to /company/view/123123 from a url like company/abc-f123123.html, although it would be useful if that was clarified and an exact test case provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all URL segments in your controller:

```
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
print_r($segments);
```

Please note that the returned array will start with index 1 instead of 0